# How do citizens of immigrant heavy countries perceive patriotism and nationalism?

Tags: citizenship, nationalism, expat

There are countries in the world that are immigrant-heavy. E.g. USA, UK, Canada, Australia, Germany, France, etc.

Other countries are monolithic. E.g. Poland, Czechia, Bulgaria, etc.

Suppose, Mr. `X` is a Polish citizen by birth. He loves his country because he loves his Polish identity and his Polish identity is directly connected to the land, the country of Poland. There is a strong sense of ownership.

On the other hand, suppose, Mr. `Y` is an English person and a citizen of the UK by birth. He regularly sees that foreigners are getting citizenship. Anyone can obtain British citizenship only in 10 years. So, his birth in the UK doesn't matter. I.e., there is no sense of ownership.

How does Mr. `Y` grow patriotism toward the UK then? And, how does he perceive British nationalism?

Comment: It's less about "ownership" and more about feelings of community and shared values. As long as the natives are a majority there are usually media supporting these. And, of course, there are usually places and even whole regions where the number of immigrants is very low. Immigrants tend to go to large urban centers, after all.

Comment: It's common to feel ownership and belonging over things you select yourself, e.g. sports teams, fans of pop singers, even religions. Are you suggesting you can't be a fan of a football team unless you were born into it? The phenomenon of zeal of the convert suggests people who choose a religion may be more strongly motivated than those who are born into it. This question seems based on an oddly narrow idea of what it means to belong to something.

Comment: The way you write it seems a foreign (sic) thought to you that some people, me included, reject patriotism as a negative sentiment. I would support your Mr. Y if he did **not** develop favorable feelings for his country, but instead acted as a rational and enlightened citizen, trying to make its politics better.

Comment: "Anyone can obtain British citizenship only in 10 years." Mr. `Y` doesn't know immigration law very well. I assume you attributed this statement to demonstrate Mr. `Y`'s ignorance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an immigrant to Canada who has also worked with immigrants, and also a native Brit, let me make some observations. However you need to be aware that patriotism is a complex thing and your two examples are nowhere near covering the full spectrum of attitudes in either country.

Let's start by saying that most immigrants have at least as much attachment to their new country as those born there. Voluntary immigrants chose the country, so they have a strong positive feeling for it (or they would have left at some stage). If they left their home country under duress then they are usually grateful to the new country for taking them in. There are cases where a country has abused immigrants, but that is true for native citizens also.

Your Mr Y seems a bit racist as well as confused. Why is obtaining citizenship by birth better than obtaining it by immigrating and demonstrating a prolonged love of the country by living there? It makes no sense unless he objects to the *kind* of people being admitted. People like Mr Y are really transferring their patriotism to an older ideal version of their country (which may or may not have ever existed in real life). It is in fact likely that Mr Y will make great claims to being patriotic despite his attitude, and leads to the kind of situation where displaying a national flag gets associated with a right wing agenda.

It should also be said that in the UK immigration is at least partly driving an upsurge in nationalism, at least in significant parts of the electorate, instead of the reverse effect your question implies. Similar things can be seen in the US.

Identity does not have to be connected to land. There are, I'm told, more people who identify as Irish in the US than there are living in Ireland. I'm cheering for Canada in the current World Cup, although I'm also keeping an eye on the English team.

Comment: I think you hit on a key point, being a citizen by birth doesn't mean you have to like/love your county of birth, However moving to another country and taking the long path to citizenship is a much better indication of your feelings towards your new home.

Comment: *I'm cheering for Canada in the current World Cup, although I'm also keeping an eye on the English team.* --- Whom would you want to win if there is a match between Canada and the UK?